# ecr token error for amazon aws docker registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Here is my registry policy for my user :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1494526914000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have no MFA auth

but when i try :

```
bussiere@kusanagi:~/Workspace/*****$ aws ecr get-login

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::*******:user/bussiere is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
bussiere@kusanagi:~/Workspace/*****$
```

[image]

[image]

thanks a lot and regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unhelpful considering you seem to have the right policy, but the permissions aren't correct somehow. Do you have the region set and are you using the keys for that user in the cli? Also as a test, does it work using the managed policy AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/common-errors.html#error-unauthorized